# How do I join three Select statement?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I already have a table that I want to transform using SQL Query.

```
CREATE TABLE Persons 
(
    Name varchar(255),
    Info varchar(255),
    Value varchar(255)
)

INSERT INTO Persons
VALUES ('Mark', 'Height', '1.6'),
       ('Mark', 'Weight', '65'),
       ('Mark', 'Hair', 'Blonde'),
       ('Angella', 'Height', '1.55'),
       ('Angella', 'Weight', '60'),
       ('Angella', 'Hair', 'Brown'),
       ('Robert', 'Height', '1.7'),
       ('Robert', 'Weight', '80')

SELECT 
    t.Name, Weight, Height, Hair
FROM 
    (SELECT Name, Value AS Weight 
     FROM Persons 
     WHERE Info = "Weight")  AS t 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT Name, Value AS Height 
     FROM Persons 
     WHERE Info = "Height") AS q ON t.Name = q.Name;
```

How do I make a query that shows me all the names in the rows and all the 'Info's as columns, and if one name doesn't have a value for an info it just left with a blank cell.

Comment: Use `OUTER JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` if you want to select all columns where just one matches

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Use single quotes for string literals. Double quotes are for delimited identifiers. (E.g. `"Weight"` seems to be a column name here.)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms Why is this so hard?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a CROSSTAB (aka PIVOT) query. Access even has a query wizard for that.

Consider:

```
TRANSFORM First(Persons.Value) AS FirstOfValue
SELECT Persons.Name
FROM Persons
GROUP BY Persons.Name
PIVOT Persons.Info;
```

| Name | Hair | Height | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Angella | Brown | 1.55 | 60 |
| Mark | Blonde | 1.6 | 65 |
| Robert |  | 1.7 | 80 |